# How to achieve a perfect square

Tags: prime-numbers

> Given a natural number $n$, compute the smallest number $k$ such that $nk$ is a perfect square.

Obviously, I have tried factorizing the number so $n=p_1^{s_1}...p_r^{s_r}$ and $k=p_{i1}...p_{il}$ where $p_{ij}\in\{p_m:m\in\{1,...,r\}:s_m\text{ is odd}\}$. Unfortunatelly (and obviously) it is veeery slow, so I get a time limit veredict.

Also I have tried compute $S\mod n$ being $S$ a perfect square such that $S\geq n$, so the first $S$ with $S\mod n = 0$ is our answer ($k=S/n$).

Comment: Why is that slow?  Seems like it's already done?  I mean, that's what $k$ is,.  Anything else would have to be equivalent to this.

Comment: Yes, the answer is right, but we need a better (faster) way to compute it so the automatic judge that will correct the program don´t run out of time.

Comment: Then this is not a math question but a programming one. For instance, if your prime factoring is unnecessarily slow then your entire program will be slow even though you might be using the indended approach. If you add your actual code to the question post, I'm sure either stackoverflow or code review (I'm not certain which would be best) is a better place.

Answer (score 3):

**Another solution**, hopefully faster:

- Find the greatest square $m$ such that
  $m^2\mid n$.

You only have to test for $m\le\sqrt n$. Note the finite differences between two consecutive squares is just the sequence of odd integers $>1$, so it should be comparatively fast.

- Then set $\;k=\dfrac n{m^2}$.

Comment: It is posible that the first $m$ is indeed $m^2$?

Comment: This depends on which value you start with. If  the first $m$ is $m^2$, it means $m=1$. I suppose you don't have to test whether  $1$ divides $n$…